# Climbing end pillars quickly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to climb end pillars quickly?
What is fastest method to climbing end pillar without getting knocked off?

Comment: Probably water buckets.

Comment: Using water buckets is slow. There is high chance of being knocked by ender dragon.

Comment: It's slow, but can't be destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing to find out the following results.

- **Climbing by making pillar :**
  [image]
- **Using water buckets :**
  [image]
- **Placing ladders while climbing:**
  [image]
- **placing vines while climbing:**
  [image]

From the results I can say that using ladders/vines is fastest method to climb.

I haven't mentioned enderperl,boat/minecart elevators here because the are not feaseable to be used in the end whilst fighting the dragon.

Comment: I concur.  Ladders are faster than jump-placing blocks

Answer (score 2):

**The best method is to use "Pillar Jumping".** Simply jump and place one block under you, then repeat until you're at the top. *Since the Ender Dragon doesn't change its flying path while charging at you, you may escape her doing this quickly.*
**Another method is to use Ender Pearls to get on the pillars.** However, you need to have a very good accuracy in order to do this, and it only works for short pillars.

Comment: 'Pillar Jumping' is also known as "Nerd-poling"